# child application cannot read parent web.config

Tags: security, web-config, iis-8

In IIS I have an important application (named treasure), with a child application (named blog). From security point of view, I decided to run both applications under their own application pools, and limit the access to the file system for each to their own directory.

So the parent application's directory is only accessible by the parent application's application pool user. (`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Treasure\` is only accessible for `IIS APPPool\treasure`)

The child application's directory is only accessible by the child application's application pool user. (`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blog` is only accessible for `IIS APPPool\blog`)

Now if I go to http://www.treasure.blah/blog/, I get an HTTP Error 500.19 - Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions - C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Treasure\web.config
lication?

I already know it is possible from the parent application's web.config to set `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"/>`. But my problem off course is that the child cannot read that web.config, but it tries to and fails. So this doesn't help me out.

How can I configure my child application so that it will NOT try to read the web.config from the parent app?

Comment: You can't. What I would do if I were you - I'd add exception just for the parent web.config file to be readable by IIS APPPool\blog.

Comment: I actually don't want to do that as the parent web.config already contains passwords and stuff.